# Why can't I import scikit-learn from Spyder, but I can import it from the command line?

Tags: python-3.x, scikit-learn, spyder

I installed Spyder 5 for MacOS Big Sur using the standalone installer on the Spyder website (i.e., no Anaconda required). I had been using Spyder 4.2.1 and successfully importing scikit-learn. However, after I installed Spyder 5, I couldn't import scikit-learn, and got a ModuleNotFound error. So I removed the "sklearn" directory from the "Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages" directory where it was placed, and re-installed scikit-learn with

```
pip install -U scikit-learn
```

as it says on the scikit-learn website. I can now import the module from my Mac's terminal command line, but when I try on Spyder, I get a long message that includes

*ImportError: dlopen(/Users/my_user_name/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages/sklearn/__check_build/_check_build.so, 2): Symbol not found: __PyThreadState_Current
Referenced from: /Users/my_user_name/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages/sklearn/__check_build/_check_build.so
Expected in: flat namespace
in /Users/my_username/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages/sklearn/__check_build/_check_build.so*

as well as

*It seems that scikit-learn has not been built correctly.*

*If you have installed scikit-learn from source, please do not forget
to build the package before using it: run `python setup.py install` or
`make` in the source directory.*

*If you have used an installer, please check that it is suited for your
Python version, your operating system and your platform.*

What can I do at this point?

Comment: The `ImportError` references `python-2.7`, does this happen with `pip3`?

Comment: @AlexanderL.Hayes, not related in the slightest. And this doesn't look like a Spyder problem but an installation one.

Comment: (*Spyder maintainer here*) if you want to use to other modules that don't come with our installer, please install [Miniconda](https://docs.conda.io/en/latest/miniconda.html), create a [conda environment](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html#creating-an-environment-with-commands) after that with the packages you want to use and `spyder-kernels`, and finally [connect Spyder](http://docs.spyder-ide.org/current/faq.html#using-existing-environment) to that env.

Comment: Thank you, Carlos. I tried your suggestion, and it didn't quite work on my machine. I'll try again, though.

Answer (score 0):

you need install Dependencies :
scikit-learn requires:

Python (>= 3.6)

NumPy (>= 1.13.3)

SciPy (>= 0.19.1)

joblib (>= 0.11)

threadpoolctl (>= 2.0.0)

for good result [requirements.txt](https://github.com/neuropoly/spinalcordtoolbox/blob/master/requirements.txt#L26)

Note:Scikit-learn 0.20 was the last version to support Python 2.7 and Python 3.4. scikit-learn 0.23 and later require Python 3.6 or newer.

`pip install scikit-learn==0.20.4`

learn more go to [this](https://pypi.org/project/scikit-learn/0.20.4/)